# Where Can I Find Library Utilization Data?

Tags: data-request, usa, government

I am interested in data on the utilization of US libraries. Ideally I would like listings of libraries with locations, a complete listing of their available catalog of books, and a history of which books were checked out when. It's fine if the check out history is de-identified.

Is there a centralized place where this data is available rather than querying individual library systems which are usually organized at the county or city level?

Comment: http://www.asdfree.com/2014/10/analyze-public-libraries-survey-pls.html  ?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look here, this looks quite promising: https://nces.ed.gov/surveys/libraries/aca_data.asp

And there is even more information available here: https://www.imls.gov/research-evaluation/data-collection/public-libraries-survey/explore-pls-data/pls-data